# Trying to upload a file via Box API /w C# returns error 500, but I can upload the same file with cURL just fine. What is wrong with my C# code?

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest, box-api

I'm trying to use Box API to upload files. I've done it in cURL with the example,

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content -k -H
 "Authorization: Bearer (access token)" -F filename=@"File path and name" -F folder_id=3015577881
```

I can upload my file, and see it just fine in the folder that I direct it to. I want to be able to do this from a C# console application.

```
var url = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));
var outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
outgoingQueryString.Add("filename", String.Format("@{0}",fileName));
outgoingQueryString.Add("folder_id", folderId);
string postData = outgoingQueryString.ToString();
var ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes(postData);
var postStream = req.GetRequestStream();
postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
postStream.Flush();
postStream.Close();
req.GetResponse();
```

With this, I get error 500. When I try to do it without the content type, I get error 405 (method_not_allowed). I've tried other content-types and they also give me 405. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use fiddler to see what the actual post request consists of in each case and compare differences.

Comment: You might consider using the official Box .Net client ([GitHub](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2), [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Box.V2/)). It does the heavy lifting for you..

Comment: @ErikE I tried running Fiddler while doing a curl request. Nothing showed up.

Comment: @JohnHoerr I forgot about that! I used it for my authentication app, but I forgot about it when making the uploading app. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnHoerr How do I upload a file that exists on my machine rather than the BoxFileRequest? That seems to just be a brand new file. Would I just use the file path and name rather than a new string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Box .Net client, you can upload a new file like this:

```
BoxFileRequest req = new BoxFileRequest()
{
    Name = "NewFile",
    Parent = new BoxRequestEntity() { Id = "0" }
};

using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(@"c:\path\to\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    BoxFile f = await client.FilesManager.UploadAsync(request, stream);                
}
```